# Blacklisting Addresses?

Tags: solidity, binance

We have been running tokens to prepare for a larger project and we have been getting sniped/botted the instant liquidity is added.  This results in this sniper dumping 20 minutes later and killing any momentum and destroying the chart.  We are looking for a way to blacklist these bots so they cannot sell.  I've been able to get the function to appear but inputting an address does nothing - the address can still buy and sell.

We have tried a variety of code from other contracts with no luck, for example:

```
    // Address that are identified as botters with holding of more than 5%.
mapping(address => bool) private _includeToBlackList;

       /**
 * @dev Exclude an address from blackList.
 * Can only be called by the current operator.
 */
function setExcludeFromBlackList(address _account) public onlyOwner {
    _includeToBlackList[_account] = false;
}

/**
 * @dev Include an address to blackList.
 * Can only be called by the current operator.
 */
function setIncludeToBlackList(address _account) public onlyOwner {
    _includeToBlackList[_account] = true;
}
```

Our contract is 0.6.12

Answer (score 1):

How about adding the following in the `_transfer` function? It would revert if the blacklisted address send or receives the token.

```
require(!_includeToBlackList[sender] && !_includetoBlackList[recipient], "This address is blacklisted");
```

On a side-note, I would personally never ever buy a token where the owner can unilaterally blacklist an address like that.